# Regular Expression for arabic numbers

Tags: jquery, html, regex, validation, arabic

I have this form that has a validation JQuery function, I have a problem with the telephone field, all I want is for the users to enter numbers only ... Its working great on the English form, but on the Arabic form, if I enter the numbers using the Arabic language the form won't submit. Anyone knows what is the regular expression for the Arabic numbers ??

Comment: I always thought the numbers we are using in in the western culture ARE Arabic ...

Comment: @Hinek there are east arabic numerals which are different. I learned that in another question here on SO...

Comment: Can you give examples of valid and invalid numbers with reasoning?

Comment: Arabic numbers are exactly equivalent to ordinary numerals, except for the different charset (but it is a bit hard to distinguish 0 from a dot).

Comment: @Hinek background  info http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_Arabic_numerals

Comment: In the link Pekka sent, the Arabic numbers work perfectly fine, but when anyone enters any of the Indian numerals I get the message from the validation function that says, user is allowed to enter numbers only ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regular Expression Arabic characters and numbers only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29729391/regular-expression-arabic-characters-and-numbers-only)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try this one:

```
/[\u0660-\u0669]/
```

Example:

```
var arNumbers = '٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩'
    ,reg_arNumbers = /^[\u0660-\u0669]{10}$/;

if (reg_arNumbers.test(arNumbers))
     alert("10 Arabic Numerals");
else
     alert("Non-Arabic Numerals");
```

Comment: I added (\u0660-\u0669) to the regular expression and it worked perfectly fine ... thanks nightS :)

Comment: You're most welcome..Your question actually made me realize that I have to update my validation functions as well =D So thank you too!

Comment: Is possible to allow arabic numbers in the input text even if the user write it in english ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `[^[:digit:]]`.

This will return any digit no matter which language including mixed languages

Comment: It doesn't really work.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely the result of unicode vs. ASCII - the regular expression should be trivial otherwise.