# Regular Expression Arabic characters and numbers only

Tags: regex, unicode, string-matching

I want Regular Expression to accept only **Arabic characters**, **Spaces** and **Numbers**.

Numbers are not required to be in Arabic.

I found the following expression:

```
^[\u0621-\u064A]+$
```

which accepts only only Arabic characters while I need Arabic characters, Spaces and Numbers.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Just add `1-9` (in Unicode format) to your character-class:

```
^[\u0621-\u064A0-9 ]+$
```

OR add `\u0660-\u0669` to the character-class which is the [range of Arabic numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_script_in_Unicode) :

```
^[\u0621-\u064A\u0660-\u0669 ]+$
```

Comment: Thank you, your expression accept تجريب123
but doesn't accept تجريب 123 تجريب 123

could you please modify it to accept spaces too

Comment: @moujtahed you just need to add a space inside the brackets.

Comment: I don't have any experience in Regular Expression formatting,

can you please post an expression accept:Arabic characters, Spaces and Numbers

Comment: @moujtahed Welcome! as Ed Cottrell says just add a space in character class! check out the edit!

Comment: it works fine in flutter  inputFormatters: [
                                              FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp("[\u0621-\u064A]+")),
                                            ],

Comment: it works fine with white space ^[\u0621-\u064A\u0660-\u0669 ]+$

Answer (score 32):

You can use:

```
^[\u0621-\u064A\s\p{N}]+$
```

`\p{N}` will match any unicode numeric digit.

To match only ASCII digit use:

```
^[\u0621-\u064A\s0-9]+$
```

---

**EDIT:** Better to use this regex:

```
^[\p{Arabic}\s\p{N}]+$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yF7gV6/2)

Comment: Thank you, your expression accept تجريب123
but doesn't accept تجريب 123 تجريب 123

could you please modify it to accept spaces too

Comment: I need to accept Arabic characters, Spaces and Numbers

Comment: you can even use: `^[\p{Arabic}\s\p{N}]+$` and see linked demo

Comment: Now I figure out the problem:

I'm using JavaScript language 
it seems that JavaScript reads Regular Expression in a different way than PHP.

Comment: @anubhava this regex is not accepting the following arabic text : عسكرياً نتيجة مهمّات

Comment: If you are using javascript, change the regex to:  `/\p{Script=Arabic}+/u`

Comment: white space not accepted i need it with arabic

Answer (score 30):

you can use 
[ء-ي]
it worked for me in javascript Jquery forme.validate rules

for my example I want to force user to insert 3 characters

[a-zA-Zء-ي]

Comment: Thank man it allows only English and Arabic "a to z" character

Comment: This find just one Arabic character what if we want to select the whole word before space

Comment: I just needed to add a white space to this to validate sentences

Answer (score 18):

use this

```
[\u0600-\u06FF]
```

it worked for me on visual studio

[image]

Answer (score 9):

With a lot of try and edit i got this for Persian names:

```
[گچپژیلفقهمو ء-ي]+$
```

Answer (score 7):

Simple, use this code:

```
^[؀-ۿ]+$
```

This works for Arabic/Persian even numbers.

Answer (score 7):

`^[\u0621-\u064Aa-zA-Z\d\-_\s]+$`

This regex must accept Arabic letters,English letters, spaces and numbers

Comment: What does `\w` mean in regex?

Comment: \w matched word characters, equivalent to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`

Answer (score 3):

This one *allows* **Arabic letters**, **Arabic numbers** and **English numbers**

```
var arabic = RegExp("^[\u0621-\u064A\u0660-\u0669 1-9]+\$");
```

Comment: added `a-zA-Z` after `1-9` to add english too

Answer (score 2):

```
function HasArabicCharacters(string text)

{

    var regex = new RegExp(

        "[\u0600-\u06ff]|[\u0750-\u077f]|[\ufb50-\ufc3f]|[\ufe70-\ufefc]");

    return regex.test(text);
}
```

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* it addresses the question.  Without that, your answer has much less educational value - remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 2):

To allow Arabic + English Letters with min&max allowed number of characters in a field, try this, tested 100%:
`^[\u0621-\u064A\u0660-\u0669a-zA-Z\-_\s]{4,35}$`
A- Arabic English letters Allowed.
B- Numbers not allowed.
C- {4,35} means the Min,Max characters allowed.
Update: On submit: Accepted English words with spaces, but the Arabic words with spaces could not be submitted!

[All cases tested](https://i.stack.imgur.com/klLpE.png)

Answer (score 1):

Regex for English and Arabic Numbers only

```
function HasArabicEnglishNumbers(text)

{

    var regex = new RegExp(

        "^[\u0621-\u064A0-9]|[\u0621-\u064A\u0660-\u0669]+$");

    return regex.test(text);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@Pattern(regexp = "^[\\p{InArabic}\\s]+$")
```

Accept arabic digit and character

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, use this:

```
preg_replace("/\p{Arabic}/u", 'x', 'abc123ابت');// will replace arabic letters with "x".
```

**Note**: For `\p{Arabic}` to match arabic letters, you need to pass `u` modifier (for unicode) at the end.

Comment: In javascript, add `Script=`: like so `/\p{Script=Arabic}/u`

Answer (score 0):

The posts above include much more than arabic (MSA) characters, it includes persian, urdu, quranic symbols, and some other symbols. The arabic MSA characters are only (see [Arabic Unicode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QmBAk.png))

```
[\u0621-\u063A\u0641-\u0652]
```

Answer (score 0):

I always use these to control user input in my apps

```
public static Regex IntegerString => new(@"^[\s\da-zA-Zء-ي]+[^\.]*$");
public static Regex String => new(@"^[\sa-zA-Zء-ي]*$");
public static Regex Email => new(@"^[\d\@\.a-z]*$");
public static Regex Phone => new(@"^[\d\s\(\)\-\+]+[^\.]*$");
public static Regex Address => new(@"^[\s\d\.\,\،\-a-zA-Zء-ي]*$");
public static Regex Integer => new(@"^[\d]+[^\.]*$");
public static Regex Double => new(@"^[\d\.]*$");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is useful example

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String thai = "1ประเทศไทย1ประเทศไทย";
    String arabic = "1عربي1عربي";

    //correct inputs
    System.out.println(thai.matches("[[0-9]*\\p{In" + Character.UnicodeBlock.THAI.toString() + "}*]*"));
    System.out.println(arabic.matches("[[0-9]*\\p{In" + Character.UnicodeBlock.ARABIC.toString() + "}*]*"));

    //incorrect inputs
    System.out.println(arabic.matches("[[0-9]*\\p{In" + Character.UnicodeBlock.THAI.toString() + "}*]*"));
    System.out.println(thai.matches("[[0-9]*\\p{In" + Character.UnicodeBlock.ARABIC.toString() + "}*]*"));
    
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This expression worked for me for arabic input with numeric value and space

```
/^[\u0621-\u064A0-9 ]+$/
```

Answer (score -1):

```
[\p{IsArabic}-[\D]]
```

An Arabic character that is not a non-digit