# ng-pattern not working correctly

Tags: angularjs

I have an input where I want to test if the inserted text is only in Arabic characters as following :

```
ng-pattern="/^([\u0600-\u06ff]|[\u0750-\u077f]|[\ufb50-\ufbc1]|[\ufbd3-\ufd3f]|[\ufd50-\ufd8f]|[\ufd92-\ufdc7]|[\ufe70-\ufefc]|[\ufdf0-\ufdfd]|[ ])*$/g"
```

this input works and accepts only Arabic values but it only accepts values that have a length of an odd number, for example when I type : `عماد` which has 4 characters it wont work but when I type : `أسماء` which has 5 characters it works.

**this is my jsfiddle :**

http://jsfiddle.net/2dznptry/

so why do I get this behavior ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pdw3udgz/)

Use following pattern:

```
ng-pattern="/^[\u0621-\u064A\u0660-\u0669 ]+$/"
```

For detail, have a look at [Regular Expression Arabic characters and numbers only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29729391/regular-expression-arabic-characters-and-numbers-only)