# Regex to replace special characters with space from English and Arabic language string using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am trying to replace special characters except numbers with the space from a string which could be in English or Arabic language.

I have used the below regex which works perfectly for English language by replacing special characters with space from the string but, in Arabic language it replace the Arabic characters too.

```
data[i].replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '');
```

Please help me to find the regex which will replace the special characters with space but not English and Arabic characters and numbers. Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regular Expression Arabic characters and numbers only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29729391/regular-expression-arabic-characters-and-numbers-only)

Comment: Add a `\w` or `a-zA-Z` to the above duplicate's answer's character class

Comment: I want to replace the special characters with space. I don't want regex which accept english and arabic language with space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `replace` everything but the Arabic and alphanumeric characters like this:

(Arabic regex borrowed from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29729405/3082296))

```js
const str = "ء-يabc##123-2++"
const replaced = str.replace(/[^\w\u0621-\u064A\s]/gi, ' ');
console.log(replaced)
```

Comment: Keep in mind that this not cover the full [Arabic Unicode range](https://unicode-table.com/en/blocks/arabic/). Which is from `0600` up to `06FF`. I don't know what the characters not included by the above mean, but you should at least take this into consideration.

Comment: @JohanWentholt interesting. In the link I mentioned, most of the answers use this range. But, [some other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40340310/3082296) do use the range you mentioned.

Comment: It comes down to each specific use case. If you want to whitelist all Arabic characters, or only Arabic letters and/or numbers (exclude things like `؆`). This is for the reader to decide and pick the ranges they seem fit.