# Regular expression to match Arabic date or normal date

Tags: java, regex

I have a scenario where a user input can be an arabic date like 
٢٠١٩-٠٣-٣٠ or normal date like 2019-07-31.

I am trying to find a regular expression which matches both cases

right now I am using the regex to match the arabic date with the one I got from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29729391/regular-expression-arabic-characters-and-numbers-only)

my code is like

```
        String s1 = "٢٠١٩-٠٣-٣٠";
        String regx = "^[\\u0621-\\u064A\\u0660-\\u0669 ]+$";
        System.out.println(regx.matches(s1));
```

but its printing false, how can I fix it, also how can I add the normal date regex to this one ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should call the `matches` method on a string and use `regx` as an argument, not the other way around. And you don't need to escape a backslash for unicode symbols. Also, add a dash and the "normal" (which are incidentally called "arabic") numerals into the regular expression, and you should get what you want:

```java
String s1 = "٢٠١٩-٠٣-٣٠";
String s2 = "03-03-2019";
String regx = "^[\\-\u0621-\u064A\u0660-\u06690-9 ]+$";
System.out.println(s1.matches(regx));
System.out.println(s2.matches(regx));
```

Note that this regular expression only validates that the string consists of valid symbols, not that it has the right format.

Comment: How can I use to convert s1 and s2 to LocaleDate ?

Comment: @robin I believe parsing the string to a date is a different question, but it seems to be already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4496359/how-to-parse-date-string-to-date

Comment: My question is how can I use the same format to parse the dates s1 and s2 ?

Comment: @robin You can't use the same format. You'd have to use something like `new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.forLanguageTag("ar-SA-nu-arab"))` to parse the arabic-indic numerals, and `new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy")` to parse a regular date.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the regex inside matches, so

```
s1.matches(regx);
```