# php regular expression to match 2 digits followed by certain words

Tags: regex, preg-match

I want to detect strings that have a user's age in them, for example :

"I'm 24 years old"
"J'ai 25 ans"

So essentially it would look for :

- starts zero or more characters (any)
- followed by two digits - match Arabic (0,1,2,etc) and Hindi (٠,١,٢, etc) numerals
- followed by one of the 'age' words (years, ans, etc)
- end with zero or more other characters (any)

I've used :

```
/^[0-9]{2} +(ans|year)$/
```

so far but it only matches very specific strings like "24 year"

Answer (score 1):

One possible approach might be

```
\b\p{N}+\s+(?:an|year)s?
```

which could be used for example in a lookahead. See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/Re0J1Y/2/).

Your initial expression uses anchors, that is your substring can only be matched at the beginning *and* the end.

Comment: Thanks that works perfectly for Arabic/Western Numerals (1,2,3, etc). How would I also make it match Hindi numerals (which are confusingly the numbers used in Arabic). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29729391/regular-expression-arabic-characters-and-numbers-only

Comment: @SherifBuzz: Aha. Changed it to `\p{N}` which should match any digits in `PCRE`.

Comment: unfortunately doesn't seem to work. I've updated the demo : https://regex101.com/r/Re0J1Y/4/

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the `^` and `$`. They match the beginning and end of the string, so it won't work if you have `I am` at the beginning or `old` at the end.

If you want to match whole words, use `\b` instead.

```
/\b\d{2} +(ans|years)\b/
```

And if you want to match numerals other than Arabic, use `\d` instead of `[0-9]`.

Comment: If you want that `\d` contains digits other than the ASCII, you have to use the u modifier (that extends shorthand character classes to unicode and turns the word-boundaries `\b` unicode aware). Also the u modifier forces the regex engine to read the string code point by code point instead of byte by byte (that is the default behavior).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I have picked the right words, yet you might want to design an expression similar to:

```
\s+\p{N}{1,3}\s+(?:years?|an(?:née)?s|سنة|سنوات|عاما|साल)
```

#### DEMO

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/NXeIFl/1) if you wish to explore/simplify/modify it.

#### Test

```
$re = '/\s+\p{N}{1,3}\s+(?:years?|an(?:née)?s|سنة|سنوات|عاما|साल)/m';
$str = 'I\'m 24 years old
J\'ai 25 ans
I have 25 year
عندي ٢٣ سنة
I\'m  24  years old
मैं 27 साल का हूँ
J\'ai  25  ans
I have 100  year
أنا 27 عاما
عندي  ٢٣  سنة';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

foreach ($matches as $match) {
    print(trim($match[0]) . "\n");
}
```

#### Output

```
24 years
25 ans
25 year
24  years
27 साल
25  ans
100  year
27 عاما
```