# Unable to read Arabic character from Wordpress REST API

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, arabic, wordpress-rest-api

I'm trying to implement search REST API for Wordpress. Everything works fine in English, however, when I enter some Arabic in the URL, it would tell me `rest_no_route`.

This it my working version for English

```php
        register_rest_route(
            'search', 
            '/keywords/(?P<value>[\w+].+)', 
            $args
        );
```

After done some [research](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42115081), it was suggest that I should add `[ء-ي]` to my regex. However, I'm not quite sure where to add in the regex as Arabic reads from right to left.

I have tried `(?P<value>[ء-ي][\w+].+)` or `[ء-ي](?P<value>[\w+].+)` it still won't work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: If you have `.+` just use `'/keywords/(?P<value>.+)'`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you so much!! Now I just need to `urldecode` the value to run sql query with it. Dziękuję Ci!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `\w` shorthand in PHP, be default, does not match Unicode letters and digits. You would need to use `(*UCP)` (probably with `(*UTF)`) PCRE verb to make it match all Unicode letters/digits. See an [example](https://regex101.com/r/qwU7M7/3).

In your case, you may simply remove `\w+` and keep `.+` to match any 1+ chars other than line break chars:

```
/keywords/(?P<value>.+)
```