# Regular expression in Arabic and English language

Tags: c#, regex

I want Regular Expression to accept only Arabic characters and Numbers, Spaces, English characters and Numbers, and `(.,:"()-_?)`

I found the following expression allow all above except `(.,:"()-_?)` :

```
ValidationExpression="[^~`!@#$%\^&\*\(\)\-+=\\\|\}\]\{\['&quot;:?.>,</]+"
```

Comment: Let's hope you didn't Google search, or your Google has problems. See [Regular Expression Arabic characters and numbers only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29729391/regular-expression-arabic-characters-and-numbers-only); it only needs a tweak or two to match your case.

Comment: Don't html encode a doublequote (`"`) like  `&quot;`, use escape instead: `\"`.

Answer (score 0):

```
"[^a-zA-Z0-9\u0621-\u064Aa\u0660-\u0669\s\)\(\-\.\:\"\?_,]+"
```

would allow arabic characters and numbers then english characters and numbers then the special characters I think you want. \u0660-\u0669 checks for arabic numbers and \u0621-\u064A checks for arabic characters. Let me know if this works and whether or not I interpreted you correctly.